# Problem connecting with LinkedIn API with UiPath

Tags: curl, automation, ui-automation, uipath

I am new to API automation because of that I am having trouble connecting my UiPath with LinkedIn API.

I already have an access token and I replaced it with {INSERT_TOKEN} as parameter in Http request wizard.

Please find the below curl that I have used:

```
curl -X GET ‘https://api.linkedin.com/v2/companySearch?q=search&query=LinkedIn%20Corporation&filter.industry[0]=6&filter.companySize[0]=H’
-H ‘Authorization: Bearer {INSERT_TOKEN}’
```

But by pressing preview, I am getting the below error message:

```
{
“serviceErrorCode”: 65604,
“message”: “Empty oauth2 access token”,
“status”: 401
}
```

Can please let me know if I missed anything or should I use different curl code, or is it an issue with my Token?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I would recommend reading up on when working with API's as they are crucial to understanding how they work (as well as helped me decipher the error you received)

First are [HTTP Response Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). In your case a 401 (Unauthorized) means you are experiencing issues with your passed credentials.

Since this is the situation, I'd assume that there is an issue with the Token being passed. Either it is in the incorrect format or a step was likely missed converting your access token into a Bearer token.

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow?context=linkedin%2Fconsumer%2Fcontext) walks you through the process of getting your Bearer token from your access token. I would recommend developing these calls in an environment that you are the most familiar with, personally I always use [Postman](https://www.postman.com/).

You will have to make a POST Request to the https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken endpoint with the token you've registered in the LinkedIn UI. This will return your bearer token used in later requests.

Once your bearer token has been issued, I would re-try the HTTP Request you tried earlier and see if the response changes.